# How to manage releases in Jira for cross functional teams on one project?

Tags: jira, release, release-management

I am a PM for different teams in a start up company, App, ML, Cloud and we have one project on Jira for all these teams, this method worked well, during development but as we get closer to release, managing releases through Jira becomes an issue. Every of these teams have their own release schedule, so I am not able to integrate 3 releases from App, ML, and cloud into releases module in Jira. What is the best way to do it? How can I create visibility to management of what goes into each release from each team through Jira? 
Thanks